# Sort array of dates with one string inside

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a query that will returns the rows grouped by my field 'forecast_date' of a order, but this info can be null, so after the 'group_by', I set a string 'Without Forecast' as the key of row that doesn't have the forecast_date.

When I want to display the rows, I need to order by the forecast_date but the rails give me a error:

`orders.keys` give me `[Tue, 08 Apr 2014, 'N/A', Tue, 09 May 2013, 01 Jan 2012]`

I try in this way:

```
@orders = Orders.where('customer_id = 9');
orders = @orders.group_by { | order | order.forecast_date.try(:to_date) } 

orders.keys.sort # And obtain this error
ArgumentError: comparison of Date with String failed
```

How can I avoid this and order correctly the rows?

Comment: please post the code for the actual query. It may be easier to determine sorting issues through sql.

Comment: Your Rails AR query is wrong in convention, where(:id=> 9) will return a single record within an AR array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a block to the sort method which determines how the elements of the array are compared. According to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sort):

> The block must implement a comparison between a and b, and return -1, when a follows b, 0 when a and b are equivalent, or +1 if b follows a.

So sorting your array could look like:

```
array.sort do |a, b|
    if a.is_a?(String)
        1
    elsif b.is_a?(String)
        -1
    else
        a <=> b
    end
end
```

It works, however, I am not sure if this is the cleanest approach out there.

Comment: Your approach solved my question :), i just reduced to one row 
order.keys.sort { |a, b| a.is_a?(String) || b.is_a?(String) ? -1 : a <=> b }

Comment: Just one more question. If i want to sort with a string (customer_name) i can use the same block in my sort?

Comment: I have edited my answer, I realised the previous version could have some trouble with proper sorting. You can use it to sort any array of Dates and Strings and the Strings will be at the end of the sorted array. But notice that the Strings at the end will be ordered somewhat randomly between each other, if you want to compare strings properly you need to implement it (you can simply use the <=> operator if both a and b are strings).

Comment: Thank you for the patience and explanation, i will implement it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `Orders` table looks like but you could do something like this

```
Order.where(customer_id: 9).order("forecast_date")
```

SQL

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders ORDER BY forecast_date
```

This will order your orders by forecast date with nil being at the end. If you wanted something like the number of orders for a given date you could do this

```
Order.where(customer_id: 9).order("forecast_date").group("forecast_date").select("count(id) as number_of_orders, forecast_date")
```

SQL

```
SELECT Count(id) as number_of_orders, forecast_date FROM orders WHERE orders.customer_id = 9 GROUP BY forecast_date ORDER BY forecast_date
```

This will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object with methods for `forecast_date` and `number_of_orders`  with `nil` `forecast_date`s at the end.

To get the dates you could call(will return an array of dates with nil at the end)

```
@orders.map(&:forecast_date)
```

You could also scope these

```
scope :by_customer,->(id){ where(customer_id: id) }
scope :grouped_by_forecast_date,->{order("forecast_date").group("forecast_date").select("count(id) as number_of_orders, forecast_date")}
```

Then you can call as `Order.by_customer(customer_id).grouped_by_forecast_date`